# Transaction Isolation Level of Serializable not working for me

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have a website which is used by all branches of a store and what it does is that it records customer purchases into a table called myTransactions.myTransactions table has a column named SerialNumber. For each purchase I create a record in the transactions table and assign a serial to it. The stored procedure that does this calls a UDF function to get a new serialNumber before inserting the record. Like below :

---

```
Create Procedure mytransaction_Insert
as begin
insert into myTransactions(column1,column2,column3,...SerialNumber) 
values( Value1 ,Value2,Value3,...., getTransactionNSerialNumber())  
end
```

---

```
Create function getTransactionNSerialNumber
as
begin
RETURN isnull(SELECT TOP (1) SerialNumber FROM myTransactions READUNCOMMITTED
ORDER BY SerialNumber DESC),0) + 1
end
```

---

The website is being used by so many users in different stores at the same time and it is creating many duplicate serialNumbers(same SerialNumbers). So I added a Sql transaction with ReadCommitted level to the transaction and I still got duplicate transaction numbers. I changed it to SERIALIZABLE in order to lock the resources and I not only got duplicate transaction numbers(!!HOW!!) but I also got sporadic deadlocks between the same stored procedure calls. This is what I tried : (With omissions of try catch blocks and rollbacks)

```
Create Procedure mytransaction_Insert
as begin
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRASNACTION ins
insert into myTransactions(column1,column2,column3,...SerialNumber) 
values( Value1 ,Value2 , Value3, ...., getTransactionNSerialNumber())  
COMMIT TRANSACTION ins
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION READCOMMITTED
end
```

I even copied the function that gets the serial number directly into the stored procedure instead of the UDF function call and still got duplicate serialNumbers.So,How can a stored procedure line create something Like the c# lock() {} block.
By the way, I have to implement the transaction serial number using the same pattern and I can't change the serialNumber to any other identity field or whatever.And for some reasons I need to generate the serialNumber inside the database and I can't move SerialNumber generation to application level.

---

Sorry but I have already tried this without READUNCOMMITTED in the function and I still get duplicate SerialNumbers.

As for the IDENTITY column, I should say that this app is going to be used by other companies that require different SerialNumbers and we can't just simply change it to identity.

Answer (score 5):

You have `READUNCOMMITTED` in the UDF.  This will cause it to ignore any exclusive locks held by other transactions.

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` is not the same as an [applock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx), it is not a "critical section" in the database, it just controls the locking behaviour of subsequent statements in the transaction.

Take out the `READUNCOMMITTED` and it should start working as you expect.

Of course, this ignores the fact that you've essentially re-implemented an `IDENTITY` column.  If your serial numbers are really incremental then you should throw all of this away and replace it with a simple `IDENTITY` column.  You claim that you "can't", but don't provide any justification for that statement; it looks to me like you almost certainly *can*.

Comment: Thanks for the sp_getapplock reference. I had no idea such thing existed!

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is a unique constraint (or primary key) down your transactions table.  If you had that the duplicate entry would back out when you attempt to commit it.

But I would state clearly that you should use the "Identity" (as said by @Aaronaught) column in SQL. This will start at whatever you want it to and increment forward or backward.  If you need your orders to start at a given number then forward it.  But if you need an identifier that is unique and also happens to be an integer value then use identity.